# OkHttp: Will there be releases in the 3.12.x branch?

Tags: git, okhttp

Not willing to split my app in flavours and alike, I'd like to stay with OkHttp 3.12.x a little longer.

The "late close" fix (https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/4651) looks important for our project now.

What I missed was, if we should clone this branch, do our own QS and build our own OkHttp 3.12.x now, or if there will be something like an release in this branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm planning to do a release this month. Going forward I hope we don't need many releases as we won't be adding new features.

Comment: This might cost me reputation, but, yes, thank you, I am looking forward to an 3.12.x release, especially with that 4651 pull request!